# Использование рекурсии для создания убывающей последовательности

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Выполнял задание на freeCodeCamp и столкнулся с проблемой - не понимаю, как работает рекурсия в конкретном примере. Не понимаю, зачем нужна const'a и как присваивание рекурсивного вызова совмещается с добавлением n в массив

Опишите, пожалуйста, как работает алгоритм на примере n = 2 или n = 3

```
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const arr = countdown(n - 1);
    arr.unshift(n);
    return arr;
  }
}
```

Comment: запустите в отладчике да пройдитесь по шагам. Он сразу в глубину убегает до конца, а на выходе добавляет текущий элемент. То есть углубились до 0, и начинаем возвращать `[]` допихаиваем туда `1` и вернули `[1]`, потом `2`, и вернули уже `[2,1]` и так далее. `const,let,var` тут роли не играет